# Vagrant on Windows 7 error: Box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

I installed Vagrant 1-7-2 on Windows 7, but I can't get it running. I followed the getting started instructions at www.vagrantup.com, this looks quite simple, but doesn't work for me. I get this error:

[image]

Comment: What's your Vagrant version? Do you can put your Vagrantfile?

Comment: I see the first words of my post were missing: "Hi I installed Vagrant 1-7-2 on Windows 7": so version 1.7.2 (the latest).

How can I post the vagrant file?

Comment: thanks! Do you can put your Vagrantfile? And run `vagrant box list`?

Comment: vagrant box list says: The are no installed boxes! Use 'vagrant box add' to add some
Here is the vagrant file: http://kopy.io/8Bw6f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause and solution: the problem was AVG Anti-virus. I disabled AVG temporary did "vagrant up" and it worked.

In found this in this post: http://www.tagwith.com/question_95494_solved-how-to-vagrant-up-with-puphpet-on-windows-7-x64-with-vagrant-1-7-2

Thanks to acfreitas for help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

After [Vagrant 1.5](http://www.vagrantup.com/blog/vagrant-1-5-and-vagrant-cloud.html) the [Vagrant Cloud](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search) is avaliable. So, vagrant find box in vagrant cloud.

This Vagrantfile Should be enough:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
end
```

However, you can try:

```
$ vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32
$ vagrant up
```

Answer (score 0):

vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32 gives this error:

[image]